# Unusual Dataframe groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I´m trying to separate the original df in groups by date. For this I have created the loop where I get the last date of previous year as the first date. But I need also to have it as the last date of current year. But for some reason I can´t see why the last group is being merged.

```
data = {'date':  ['2017-03-31', '2017-04-03', '2017-12-27', '2017-12-28',
                    '2017-12-29', '2018-01-02', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-02',
                    '2019-01-03', '2019-12-31', '2020-12-30', '2020-12-31',
                    '2021-01-20', '2021-12-30', '2021-12-31', '2022-05-30',
                    '2022-05-31'],
        'value': [1163.00, 1221.15, 1318.84, 1384.78,
                    1523.26, 1660.36, 1710.17, 1881.18,
                    1956.43, 2015.12, 2216.64, 2349.63,
                    2373.13, 2562.98, 2819.28, 2875.66,
                    2904.42 ]          
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
d = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df2 = df[df.groupby(d.dt.year, as_index=False).cumcount(ascending=False).eq(0)].assign(year=d.dt.year+1)
datas = df2.date.to_list()
datas.insert(0, '2017-01-01')

for a, b in zip(datas, datas[1:]):
    str = "'" + a + "' <= date <= '" + b +"'"
    print(f'{df.query(str)}\n')
```

the queries should execute each of these blocks:

```
'2017-01-01' <= date <= '2017-12-29'
'2017-12-29' <= date <= '2018-12-31'
'2018-12-31' <= date <= '2019-12-31'
'2019-12-31' <= date <= '2020-12-31'
'2020-12-31' <= date <= '2021-12-31'
'2021-12-31' <= date <= '2022-05-31'
```

Comment: I need to concatenate this 6 queries. the loop should execute:

`df.query("'2017-01-01' <= date <= '2017-12-29'")
df.query("'2017-12-29' <= date <= '2018-12-31'")
df.query("'2018-12-31' <= date <= '2019-12-31'")
df.query("'2019-12-31' <= date <= '2020-12-31'")
df.query("'2020-12-31' <= date <= '2021-12-31'")
df.query("'2021-12-31' <= date <= '2022-05-31'")`

Comment: Your code seems to be doing that already

Comment: @mozway Please try the code. The last block is wrong, maybe something with the bounderies of the loop.

Comment: I get `2021-12-31, 2022-05-30, 2022-05-31` as dates for the last group, can you provide your output and the desired output?

Comment: I´m sorry! My jupiter notebook collapsed the last block. the code is correct. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can duplicate the overlapped row to assign it to 2 groups:

```
dup = d.dt.year.ne(d.shift().dt.year).shift(-1, fill_value=False).add(1)
df1 = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(dup))

gid = df1.index.duplicated(keep='first').cumsum() + 1
out = dict(list(df1.assign(group=gid).groupby(gid, as_index=False)))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
{1:          date    value  group
 0  2017-03-31  1163.00      1
 1  2017-04-03  1221.15      1
 2  2017-12-27  1318.84      1
 3  2017-12-28  1384.78      1
 4  2017-12-29  1523.26      1,
 2:          date    value  group
 4  2017-12-29  1523.26      2
 5  2018-01-02  1660.36      2
 6  2018-12-31  1710.17      2,
 3:          date    value  group
 6  2018-12-31  1710.17      3
 7  2019-01-02  1881.18      3
 8  2019-01-03  1956.43      3
 9  2019-12-31  2015.12      3,
 4:           date    value  group
 9   2019-12-31  2015.12      4
 10  2020-12-30  2216.64      4
 11  2020-12-31  2349.63      4,
 5:           date    value  group
 11  2020-12-31  2349.63      5
 12  2021-01-20  2373.13      5
 13  2021-12-30  2562.98      5
 14  2021-12-31  2819.28      5,
 6:           date    value  group
 14  2021-12-31  2819.28      6
 15  2022-05-30  2875.66      6
 16  2022-05-31  2904.42      6}
```

**Update**

Are you looking for:

```
dup = d.dt.year.ne(d.shift().dt.year).shift(-1, fill_value=False).add(1)
df1 = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(dup))

gid = df1.index.duplicated(keep='first').cumsum() + 1
df1 = df1.assign(group=gid).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
          date    value  group
0   2017-03-31  1163.00      1
1   2017-04-03  1221.15      1
2   2017-12-27  1318.84      1
3   2017-12-28  1384.78      1
4   2017-12-29  1523.26      1
5   2017-12-29  1523.26      2
6   2018-01-02  1660.36      2
7   2018-12-31  1710.17      2
8   2018-12-31  1710.17      3
9   2019-01-02  1881.18      3
10  2019-01-03  1956.43      3
11  2019-12-31  2015.12      3
12  2019-12-31  2015.12      4
13  2020-12-30  2216.64      4
14  2020-12-31  2349.63      4
15  2020-12-31  2349.63      5
16  2021-01-20  2373.13      5
17  2021-12-30  2562.98      5
18  2021-12-31  2819.28      5
19  2021-12-31  2819.28      6
20  2022-05-30  2875.66      6
21  2022-05-31  2904.42      6
```

Comment: This is  interesting. Can it be transformed in a Dataframe with an additional column G like:
                date      value      group
 0  2017-03-31  1163.00           1
 1  2017-04-03  1221.15           1
 2  2017-12-27  1318.84           1 
 3  2017-12-28  1384.78           1
 4  2017-12-29  1523.26           1
 5  2017-12-29  1523.26           2
 6  2018-01-02  1660.36           2
 7  2018-12-31  1710.17           2 .... and so on?

Comment: sorry I couldn´t format as I wished.

Comment: I tried to convert this dictonary to a Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(list(out.items()),columns = ['column1','column2'])
Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do exactly? `df = pd.concat(out.values())` I updated my answer, can you check it please?